# How can I make a readline await async promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, readline

On NodeJS I need to make a grep like function for log research purposes and I'm trying to make it using readline (since I don't want readline-sync). I've read many messages, tutorials, documentation, stackoverflow posts, and so on, but I couldn't understood how to make it works.

```js
const grep = async function(pattern, filepath){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        let fresult = ``;

        let lineReader = require(`readline`).createInterface({
            input: require(`fs`).createReadStream(filepath)
        });

        lineReader.on(`line`, function (line) {
            if(line.match(regex)){
                fresult += line;
            }
        });

        resolve(fresult);
    });
}

let getLogs = await grep(/myregex/gi, filepath);
console.log(getLogs);
```

Which gives me:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Where am I wrong? I feel like I'm good but did a beginner mistake which is dancing just under my eyes.

Comment: Node supports top-level await (without need for encapsulation inside an `async` function) since version 14.3. https://pprathameshmore.medium.com/top-level-await-support-in-node-js-v14-3-0-8af4f4a4d478

Comment: @JeremyThille true, but at this time you have to define your script/project as `type:module`, which for existing projects means quite a bit of refactoring (for course, if this is a new script, then it's easy to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the other answers have missed is that you have two problems in your code.

### The error in your question:

Top level await (`await` not wrapped in an `async` function) is only possible when running Node.js "as an ES Module", which is when you are using `import {xyz} from 'module'` rather than `const {xyz} = require('module')`.

As mentioned, one way to fix this is to wrap it in an async function:

```
// Note: You omitted the ; on line 18 (the closing } bracket)
// which will cause an error, so add it.

(async () => {
let getLogs = await grep(/myregex/gi, filepath);
console.log(getLogs);
})();
```

A different option is to save your file as `.mjs`, not `.js`. This means you must use `import` rather than `require`.

The third option is to create a `package.json` and specify `"type": "module"`. Same rules apply.

### A more fundamental issue:

When you call `resolve()` the event handler in `lineReader.on('line')` will not have been executed yet. This means that you will be resolving to an empty string and not the user's input. Declaring a function `async` does nothing to wait for events/callbacks, after all.

You can solve this by waiting for the 'close' event of Readline & only then resolve the promise.

```
const grep = async function(pattern, filepath){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        let fresult = ``;

        let lineReader = require(`readline`).createInterface({
            input: require(`fs`).createReadStream(filepath)
        });

        lineReader.on(`line`, function (line) {
            if(line.match(regex)){
                fresult += line;
            }
        });

        // Wait for close/error event and resolve/reject
        lineReader.on('close', () => resolve(fresult));
        lineReader.on('error', reject);
    });
}; // ";" was added

(async () => {
  let getLogs = await grep(/myregex/gi, 'foo');
  console.log("output", getLogs);
})();
```

### A tip

The `events` module has a handy utility function named `once` that allows you to write your code in a shorter and clearer way:

```
const { once } = require('events');
// If you're using ES Modules use: 
// import { once } from 'events'

const grep = async function(pattern, filepath){
    // Since the function is 'async', no need for 
    // 'new Promise()'

    let regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    let fresult = ``;

    let lineReader = require(`readline`).createInterface({
        input: require(`fs`).createReadStream(filepath)
    });

    lineReader.on(`line`, function (line) {
        if(line.match(regex)){
            fresult += line;
        }
    });

    // Wait for the first 'close' event
    // If 'lineReader' emits an 'error' event, this
    // will throw an exception with the error in it.
    await once(lineReader, 'close');
    return fresult;
};

(async () => {
  let getLogs = await grep(/myregex/gi, 'foo');
  console.log("output", getLogs);
})();

// If you're using ES Modules: 
// leave out the (async () => { ... })();
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the function call into an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(async()=>{
  let getLogs = await grep(/myregex/gi, filepath);
  console.log(getLogs);
})()
```

Comment: add semicolon at the beginning of the function ;(async()=>{

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
async function run(){

let getLogs = await grep(/myregex/gi, `/`);
console.log(getLogs);
}

run();
```